# PHP script display image BLOB executed twice?

Tags: php, database, image, blob

I couldn't find a succinct way to summarise the question in the title, allow me to elaborate:

I have a website that uses a PHP script "getImg.php" that takes an image binary object from my database and display it when called by the HTML img tag on a separate page.

I would like to log the number of times people view images so I added a simple line to increment the 'views' property for the appropriate image.

I thought this would be simple, but it turns out that it increments twice. My bodgy way around this was to make the 'views' column a float and increment by 0.5 to result with a 1 increment. However, I viewed my database today to find 0.5 in some images!

When I comment out the end print it works properly. I assumed the call from the HTML tag plus the script itself counts for two calls? But this doesn't seem to be the case with other people.

Is this just my set up?

```
<?php

# Connect to db
include('db.php');

# Get ID
$id = $_GET['id'];
if(!is_numeric($id)) exit;

$q = $db->prepare("SELECT tNail,image,format FROM gallery WHERE id = '$id'");
$q->execute();
$row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(array_key_exists("thumb", $_GET))
    $img = base64_decode($row["tNail"]);
else
{
    $img = base64_decode($row["image"]);

    # Add to views if not thumb
    // 0.5 because script called twice due to print?
    $db->query("UPDATE gallery SET views = (views + 0.5) WHERE id = '$id'");
}

switch($row["format"])
{
    case ".jpg":
        header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
        break;
    case ".png":
        header("Content-type: image/png");
        break;
}

print $img;

?>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why dedicate an entire column to the file extension? Why not just read the mime type of the flie on load? Also, thumbnails need not be stored as a seperate column, you should have php generate a resized image. All of the above will save a _lot_ of space in your database and are much more efficient.

Comment: I use a generator to process large amounts of images so pushing as much load on the generator and DB as possible seems like a more efficient method, since it requires only a query to find it. Would it make much of a difference to do it your way? The only benefit would be saving storage space, right? The generator script DOES resize the image. I'd rather take load off the preprocessor. I'd rather favour visitor load times than DB space.

Comment: It will save space and not put any noticeable stain on the server. Contrary to the way many see it, image manipulation is a simple task for the server to complete. It puts a negligible strain on the server, if any. I'll see if I can find a good write up. Most big web services use this method.

Comment: OK thanks. Do you have any idea what may be causing my double increments?

Comment: Why not echo as opposed to print?

Comment: Personal anal preference. I like print over echo haha

Comment: But does using echo present the same problem?

Comment: That's a good question, I'll try it. I wouldn't expect it to since they differ very slightly.

Comment: I tried it to no avail. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Maybe it is a brwoser issue? With which browsers do you have tested it? Browsers like chrome could be prefetch the images so it is loaded once and if the user clicks on it then it is loaded twice.

Comment: I think it does have something to do with my browser. I've tested it only with Firefox 14.0.1 yet I see evidence of other people viewing images and incrementing by 0.5 so their browser acts differently.

Comment: Aha! Tested with K-meleon it behaves correctly. So it must be some setting within firefox, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a brwoser issue. Browsers like Chrome could prefetch the images so it is loaded once and if the user clicks on a link to a image - it is loaded twice.

**Check**:

Load a image with your browser and then check your apache access.log and if you see 2 request at the same time it is a browser issue.

Comment: You are correct. This behaves incorrectly with FF 14.0.1 but fine with K-meleon. Is this something that I cannot avoid?

Comment: Thanks for that, yes it is asking for two requests

Answer (score 2):

Here's your problem:

```
if(array_key_exists("thumb", $_GET))
    $img = base64_decode($row["tNail"]);
else
{$img = base64_decode($row["image"]);//<==
```

You're starting this `if...else` branch as a 1-line deal, but in the else case you're executing a code block. php starts executes that 1 line below if, skips else and the first subsequent line and carries on as if the closing barcket weren't there. It's somewhat of a bug I reckon. I've been hearing a lot of people complaining about this lately. (since 5.3.7 or something). Set your ini to `E_STRICT` error reporting and check if that makes any difference

---

Looks like Besnik found it before I started to even look into it (well done and +1). @Lee: Here's how to avoid this issue:

```
RewriteEngine On
SetEnvIfNoCase X-Forwarded-For .+ proxy=yes
SetEnvIfNoCase X-moz prefetch no_access=yes

# block pre-fetch requests with X-moz headers
RewriteCond %{ENV:no_access} yes
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

Found this [here](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/modrewrite-tips-tricks.html#Stop_browser_prefetching)

---

```
if(array_key_exists("thumb", $_GET))
{
    $img = base64_decode($row["tNail"]);
}
else
{
    $img = base64_decode($row["image"]);
    $db->query("UPDATE gallery SET views = (views + 0.5) WHERE id = '$id'");
}
```

If either of the branches are missing curly braces that could cause issues. Again: if the if statement isn't contained in a code block, only the first statement (all code up to the first semi-colon) following the else statement will be interpreted as a branch. This is the assignment to the `$img` variable in your case. The database insert will be called in both cases.

You could check to see weather or not the db query is executed using the `__halt_compiler`:

```
if(array_key_exists("thumb", $_GET))
{
    $img = base64_decode($row["tNail"]);
}
else
{
    $img = base64_decode($row["image"]);
    if ($db->query("UPDATE gallery SET views = (views + 0.5) WHERE id = '$id'"))
    {
        if (array_key_exists("thumb", $_GET))
        {//this should be an impossible branch
            __halt_compiler();//or exit || throw if this is a (member) function
        }
    }
}
```

the `__halt_compiler()` function cannot be used in any other scope but the global namespace, and only affects the current script being executed, if this script is an include of -for example- the `index.php`, the index.php will carry on as is, but the include script will halt. [Read the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.halt-compiler.php) for a more comprehensive explanation (I suck at explaining things).

---

All this won't help you avoid this issue while figuring this one out, so I'd suggest this fugly work around for now:

```
if(array_key_exists("thumb", $_GET))
{
    $img = base64_decode($row["tNail"]);
    $db = null;//disconnect
}
else
{
    $img = base64_decode($row["image"]);
    if ($db !== null)
    {//or $db instanceof PDO (or whatever object you're using)
     //or try{$db->query('UPDATE...');}catch(Exception $e){}//<- suppress exception
        $db->query("UPDATE gallery SET views = (views + 0.5) WHERE id = '$id'");
    }
}
```

Let me know which of the above works, or if you're still encountering the same problem. I find this a very curious and therefore interesting case :)

Comment: hm, I changed the error reporting and even added the usual braces for the if statement but nothing changed. When I comment out the print construct it increments properly, very strange.

Comment: Very curious indeed, I'll have a look at when I've finished work. Hard to fathom what's happening here... always interesting to work it out!

Comment: @Lee: Let me know if the rewrite rule works out, it might just come in handy one day

Comment: Thanks for that. mod_rewrite.so is already enabled, but when I create the .htaccess and place it in the site's HTML folder nothing seems to have changed. I have no experience with .htaccess. Is it enough to just paste that into a blank .htaccess file?

Comment: and enable the `mod_rewrite` on your webserver, and probably best set your RewriteEngine on, and possibly declare a rewrite base etc... all the usual: read the link, it's a bit tricky to start off with, but well worth it

Comment: Hm, I've tried several variants of the above .htaccess commands, however they have no effect. Looking at my apache access log I have the suspicion that this may not actually be a pre-fetching problem as there are no pre-fetching headers shown in the log file. Should there be?

Comment: @Lee: you've done the .htaccess mod rewrite and changed the branching, too? for clarity, I'll update my answer to the `if-else` branches I'm assuming you have at this poit